# Run Python script in impala-shell

Tags: python, sql, variables, impala

I am able to run a text file that has queries delimited by ';' in the impala-shell. However, I have some queries that require the results of another query. For example, if Query1 gives me `name | age | birthday` and then the following query is something like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE age in (...)`, and those ages are from the age column from the first query.

I know you can specify with `--vars` option, but that seems to be for inserting specific values. Is there a way to create Python script to handle something like this that would run in the impala-shell?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating temp tables will help here. 
Impala Only solution -
step 0 - load the table from file.
step 1 - create temp table tmp_table as Query 1.
step 2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE age in (tmp_table).
step 3 - Drop table tmp_table.
You can use subquery as well in case all are in impala tables.
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE age in (select age from Query1)

Yes, you can always use python to run impala-shell queries. But they will be like call scripts one after another and for your requirement you can do them entirely in impala.

Answer (score 0):

You can create scripts `.sh` or `.py` or `.???` and run them from the `impala shell`.

To invoke the linux shell command line from `impala-shell` type:

```sh
impala> shell <linux shell command>;
```

as an example

```sh
[localhost.localdomain:21000] > shell ls -ltr /home;
[localhost.localdomain:21000] > shell hdfs dfs -ls /;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > shell spark-submit --master yarn /home/cloudera/query.py;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > shell /home/cloudera/check-services.sh;
Graphite: ko
Zookeeper: ko
KafkaServer: ko
--------

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > shell python /home/cloudera/executable.py
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query can have another `resultset` in it:

```
select name from customers
 where customer_id in (select customer_id from tableX);

.or.

with AAA as (select customer_id from tableXYZ
              where purchase_count > 20
                and date_purch >= '2022-01-01')
select b.* 
  from BBB b
  LEFT INNER JOIN AAA a on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id)
;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).